# Questions about using I/O

Tags: python, printing, io

```
fp_r = open("Team_Assignment.txt", 'r')

for s in fp_r:
    if "Altos" in s:
        print("%s: DF = %s, OF = %s" %(s[0:2], s[4], s[8]))
    else:
        print("%s: DF = %s, OF = %s" %(s[0:2], s[4], s[8]))

while True:
    a = input("Enter names to wap: ")
    if not a:
        break
    print(a)

fp_r.close()
```

I have written code like this. I know something is wrong with what I wrote, but I don't know how to fix it.

Team_Assignment.txt is this.

```
 Aa  8   4   Altos
 Ba  7   6   Webee
 Ca  4   7   Altos
 Da  5   5   Webee
 Ea  2   9   Altos
 Fa  9   3   Webee
 Ga  7   8   Altos
 Ha  6   4   Webee
```

From left, it is name, DF, OF, and team name.

I want to print like this (in Shell)

```
**Altos** DF = 21 OF = 28
Ann: DF = 8, OF = 4
Pia: DF = 4, OF = 7
Eric: DF = 2, OF = 9
Susan: DF = 7, OF = 8

**Webee** DF = 27 OF = 18
Henry: DF = 7, OF = 6
Tom: DF = 5, OF = 5
Noah: DF = 9, OF = 3
Jin: DF = 6, OF = 4

Enter names to swap: Ann Herny

**Altos** DF = 20 OF = 30
Henry: DF = 7, OF = 6
Pia: DF = 4, OF = 7
Eric: DF = 2, OF = 9
Susan: DF = 7, OF = 8

**Webee** DF = 28 OF = 16
Ann: DF = 8, OF = 4
Tom: DF = 5, OF = 5
Noah: DF = 9, OF = 3
Jin: DF = 6, OF = 4

Enter names to swap:
```

As you can see, `**Altos** DF = 21 OF = 28` and `**
Webee ** DF = 27 OF = 18` are missing. And Altos wasn't tied to Altos or Webee to Webee.

Comment: You have to split your line to get individual values. Then save the data in an appropriate datastructure so that you can sum up the values you need.

Comment: Can you write more specific?

Comment: Don't try to tackle everything at once. It seems it's time to learn the basics. Go to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/. Use the search and search for _split_. You'll get a list and since you're working with strings you follow the link to `str.split`. Read the info and apply it to your problem. Then take the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing you files in JSON format. It will be much easier that way.

### Example:-

**data.json** :-

```
{
  "data": [
    { "name": "John Doe", "score": 5 },
    { "name": "Emily", "score": 10 }
  ]
}
```

**main.py** :-

```py
import json

with open("./data.json", "r") as file:
  data = json.loads(file.read())
  for entry in data["data"]:
    name = entry["name"]
    score = entry["score"]
    print(f"{name} has scored {score} points")
```

Comment: I was told to use it in txt format. And I have never learned Java script. What should I do in txt format?